# Facebook Graph API rate limit for page access_token blocks all my requests, how to get current page tokens?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post to a Facebook page using the graph api and a page access_token. Before that I've done the app review for manage_pages and publish_pages and verified as an indivual.

Current state after successful app-review is, that none of my known page access_tokens (I only need one for my app normally) is working any more, I cannot create a new one neither.

The results I get, when I try to create a page_access token and the app is live:

`Page access tokens cannot be generated: Application request limit reached You can try entering your own token instead.`

The result I get, when I try to access the live app using a old access_token, which is currently valid (checked using token debugger):

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Application request limit reached",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "is_transient": false,
    "code": 4,
    "error_subcode": 1349193,
    "error_user_title": "Exceeded asset access limit",
    "error_user_msg": "You have exceeded asset access limit for the calling user. For asset type page, there is a limit to 3 instances the app can access for the caller.",
    "fbtrace_id": "FH0smYxLeYh"
  }
}
```

The access_token I get with `/me/accounts` using a user access_token isn't working either.

- How can I reset all page access_tokens?
- How can I get a working access_token, which I can fill in the debugger to extend it?
- Do you have any other suggestion to make this work?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I have an long-time approved app that was working fine. But FB suddenly started giving me this same error when I was using the app. However, FB is not giving at least some other users this error. I cannot explain it. Perhaps waiting will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

7 days after I posted this question it seems like Facebook automatically lifted those rate limits, as my live app began to work without any changes made (correct prior working access token set). So the solution in this particular case is just wait.

Comment: I will wait 1 week from today :D 
Let me share the result after that.